# Save files to specific folders

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking for a vba function that can take a file saved and downloaded from email and save that pdf under a specific folder. Is there some vba code or function that is able to perform this function. The user should be able to download the file first so it will be at least in downloads. They will only need to select the file and it should upload to the proper folder.

I have tried looking but online there is only code to upload files online.

I am hopeful there is a way to do this. I will be grateful to the legends that can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the source location for the file is already known (given that you are prompting the user to select the file to be moved), then although you have mentioned three distinctly different operations in your question (*"save file"* / *"download file"* / *"upload file"*), I believe the task is purely to *move* the file to a target location.

The easiest way to accomplish this in VBA is using a [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement) statement, e.g.:

```
Dim srcFnm As String: srcFnm = "YourFile.pdf"
Dim srcPth As String: srcPth = "C:\YourSourceFolder"
Dim tarPth As String: tarPth = "C:\YourTargetFolder"

Name srcPth & "\" & srcFnm As tarPth & "\" & srcFnm
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement):

> The `Name` statement renames a file and moves it to a different directory or folder, if necessary. `Name` can move a file across drives, but it can only rename an existing directory or folder when both `newpathname` and `oldpathname` are located on the same drive. `Name` cannot create a new file, directory, or folder.

Note that last line *"`Name` cannot create a new file, directory, or folder."*, hence you'll need to first ensure that the target folder exists before attempting to move the file.

For this, you can use a combination of the [`dir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) function and [`mkdir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mkdir-statement) function, e.g.:

```
If Dir(tarPth, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then MkDir tarPth
```

Comment: Thank you.  Essentially a fancy move file is all that is required. Thank you for pointing this out as I was trying to look too hard into saving rather than moving. All I had to was find the file name and path using selected and then similar to name I used FSO.MoveFile. Thank you for the answer.